# How to show video obtained from a http request in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, parsing, httprequest, multipart

Here I got a URL. I can't provide the whole string but part of it is "http://***/video.mjpg".
When I open it with browser(firefox), it shows the video. When I analyze the package using Fiddler, it shows this:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server:***

Pragma:no-cache

Cache-Control:no-cache

Content-Type:multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary="myboundary"

I search the Internet and I got the these key word: MIME, dynamic parsing. But I still don't have a clue how to parse it. Hope anyone could help me. How to parse the message in Java and Objective-C to display the video content in Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

for iOS you can use

**EDIT**

```
NSString *url = @"http://*/video.mjpg";
NSError *error = nil;

videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:url] options:nil error:&error];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videoToPlay.mp4"];

[videoData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
NSURL *moveUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]init];
[player setContentURL:moveUrl];
player.view.frame = viewPlayer.bounds;
[viewPlayer addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

have a look at this for a [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092) from Apple

for Android

I am not an Android developer but i had used this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200011/video-streaming-and-android)
for a demo i tested.

Comment: I've tried this method for iOS before, it showed a whole white screen. Then I trid the Android solution you post, my phone began to download but fail to download anything. Still showed nothing on screen.

Comment: then may be you need to first download the whole video and then play it, try the new code, edited my answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The server is like a kind of IP camera. So it is a continuous streaming. I think it's impossible to download the whole video. It's better to parse every frame of the video from the stream. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For android:

```
if (the_link_of_the_video_here.startsWith("http://") == false){
the_link_of_the_video_here="http://"+the_link_of_the_video_here;
}
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(the_link_of_the_video_here));
startActivity(intent);
```

the_link_of_the_video_here is the link that u received from the http request

Comment: Doesn't work. The application shows "Start Dowloading" but fail to download anything. The screen shows nothing. My URL contains username and password like this "http://username:password@domain***". Is this the problem?

Comment: What I think the problem is the video stream
try to use rtsp stream instead of http stream I think it will work, because this always happen to me so I ask the client to give me rtsp 
good luck :)