# Android video streaming from url

Tags: android, video-streaming

I use following code to play video from a url. It works fine except that It first downloads video and then plays that video

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
  video.setVideoURI(uri);
  video.start();
```

But I want to  stream the live  video instead of downloading it and then play

Comment: It should stream - what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Can you post the URL to the video so we can test if streaming is supported or not

Comment: Any video from youtube can be taken as sample

Comment: Here is a similar question. Check this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200011/video-streaming-and-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have work on YouTube Video streaming and that was without downloading video. 
This will only work if you will play YouTube video .

You have to use YouTube API and using that you can easily manage your task.

You have to enable YouTube service and using `Developer Key` you can access YouTube API.

[How to use YouTube API ?](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2) You can [Find Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5c6hbss51mdtg6z/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.0.0.zip) Sample code for same.

Out of that sample example i have use

`PlayerViewDemoActivity.java` & `YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity.java` and that XMl view as per the needs.

**Play Video**

```
public class PlayerViewDemoActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity
{
    String  youtube_id = "_UWXqFBF86U";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playerview_demo);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view); // Replace your developer key
        youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored)
    {
        if (!wasRestored)
        {
            player.cueVideo(youtube_id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider()
    {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

}
```

Hope this will be help you,Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: I need to stream videos from my server as well!!

Comment: @SourabhSaldi okay,i have post my answer base on your  comment that `test any youtube video`.BTW you can add permission in config file so that video will not download while you streaming from server

Answer (score 3):

There are some requirements for streaming to work.

**The file might not be encoded "correctly"**

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

> For video content that is streamed over HTTP or RTSP, there are additional requirements:
>
> - For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the `moov` atom must precede any `mdat` atoms, but must succeed the `ftyp` atom.
> - For 3GPP, MPEG-4, and WebM containers, audio and video samples corresponding to the same time offset may be no more than 500 KB apart. To minimize this audio/video drift, consider interleaving audio and video in smaller chunk sizes.

**You might be on an older version of Android that doesn't support it**

HTTP progressive streaming was only added in 2.2, HTTPS only supported 3.0+, Live streaming is only supported in even later versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL); //Declare your url here.

VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview)
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));       
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

Another Method:

```
  String LINK = "type_here_the_link";
  VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
  MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
  mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
  mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
  Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
  mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
  mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
  mVideoView.start();
```

If you are getting this error [Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side Error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832379/couldnt-open-file-on-client-side-trying-server-side-error-in-android). and also [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620049/how-to-play-video-from-url).
Hope this will give you some solution.

Answer (score 0):

For showing buffering you have to put `progressbar` of `ProgressDialog` ,... here i post `progressDialog` for buffering ...

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoView);      

        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    });
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            finish();               
        }
    });
```