# Using youtube to play in app purchasble videos

Tags: android, web-services, youtube-api, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

Is it possible to use the Youtube API on adroid to play a video that is only available after an in app purchase?

For example I have a teaser video, which is free. And the full video which will be sold to the user.  I am having trouble setting up my web server to stream the .3gp files to my app (by trouble i mean completely lost).

Will youtube let me keep the videos private, since I am trying to sell them?

If it is not possible does anyone have advice on how to set up my webserver to stream .3gp videos? (I know very little about servers)

Answer (score 0):

While you can set YouTube videos to unlisted, your use of YouTube in this way is probably going to be a [violation of the API's terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). Note that I cannot officially interpret the ToS for you, but it seems like this would be against this provision:

> You agree not to use the YouTube API for any of the following
>   commercial uses unless You obtain YouTube's prior written approval:
>
> - the sale of the YouTube API, API Data, YouTube audiovisual content
>     or related services, or access to any of the foregoing;

There are any number of ways to stream video from a server, and I'm not sure I can give you a comprehensive answer. However, [here's one possible approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200011/video-streaming-and-android) for consuming video from the Android side. On the server side, you might want to learn some more about server side programming before you dig in, but it seems like you could host video files publicly on a web server and just point to those URLs - if you want something a bit more complex, like authentication, you'll probably have to write your own code to do so in a custom web server. One way of doing this might be the [bottle.py framework's static file](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files) serving handler combined with Nginx.