# android to android live video stream via Wifi direct (P2P)

Tags: android, video-streaming, wifi-direct

I have two android devices(phones).Let's call P1 and P2. I'm writing two apps, one for live-stream P1's camera video and other for view that video (from P2). 
I want to connect these two devices via wifi Direct (No router). I have searched the internet for days now on how to implement a video streaming feature from an android phone to another android phone over a WiFi connection but not using Wifi direct (p2p). 
Here I specifically want to do this via wifi direct. Can someone help me ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi. What exactly are you looking for? How to capture the video and send it, or how to establish a wifi-p2p connection? You say you've looked for video streaming over standard wifi, so I guess you've already found some of the solutions and are looking for wifi-p2p?

Comment: Take a look at [android.net.wifi.p2p](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html)

Comment: Hi, now I'm looking this kind of application. Did you achieve it? if you achieved let me know it. Thanks

Comment: If I am streaming high definition video, what is the number of nodes that a Group Owner support to have a realistic and good stream ? ie, what are the capabilities of a non entry level device in respect to number of other devices (slaves) it can support?

Answer (score 14):

A few thoughts:

1. To manage the WiFi direct/p2p connection you could use something like:

   - [android.net.wifi.p2p](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html)
2. To stream the video from a device, checkout these open-source examples

   - [spydroid ipcamera](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)
   - [ipcamera for android](http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/)
   - [SIPDroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/ui/VideoCamera.java)
3. To handle displaying the video, (depending on the video stream) you could use:

   - An updating [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)
   - A [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

     - See: [Video Streaming and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200011/video-streaming-and-android)
   - A [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use ES Explorer APP from Google play

In App setting there is remote setting and check it and an ftp ip  address like

- > **"ftp://*******************

  will appear.

On the other device ES Explorer APP file menu select Ftp and add server and enter the ip address from other device.

the first device will appear on second device now

Go it file system play videos

enjoy...........................